Getting errors trying to use python requests connection
trying to make a connection using 4 arguments.
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
'Cookie': 'A'}

body = {
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "test client",
"client_secret": "client secret",
"scope": "read"}

conn.request("POST", url, headers, json.dumps(body))

I am getting an error as below
    [ERROR] 2024-08-20T17:30:28.313Z cadf1225-4977-4fa2-8435-1b6f650d0e55 
   Canary error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/var/task/index.py", 
   line 92, in handle_canary response = handler(event, context) File      "/opt/python/apiCanaryBlueprint.py", line 77, in handler main() File "/opt/python/apiCanaryBlueprint.py", line 70, in main verify_request(method1, url1, payload1, headers1) File "/opt/python/apiCanaryBlueprint.py", line 27, in verify_request conn.request(method, url, headers=json.dumps(body)) File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1285, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked) File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1325, in _send_request for hdr, value in headers.items(): AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`


Hi Girish, can you try passing your arguments via keywords? conn.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=body) it seems like you are passing the json body string as the headers parameter.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

thanks Mark. I had  tried passing arguments via keywords and got an error  conn.request("POST", url, headers=myownheaders, json=myownpayload, )
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'

Try direct definition of function parameters:
conn.request(method="POST", url=url, headers=headers, body=json.dumps(body))

The request is changing your headers value type from dictionary to string, probably because of the wrong parameter order.
You can also use post function: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-requests-post-request-with-headers-and-body/
